# Docker Run fails for a Python Project

Tags: python, docker

I have the following project structure for one of my Python project:

```
raspi-motion-detection
|-- project
    |-- core
        |-- motion_detector.py
    |-- conf
        |-- conf.json
```

I then have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM     jfloff/alpine-python
RUN      mkdir -p /raspi_motion_detection/project
WORKDIR  /raspi_motion_detection/project
COPY     ./ $WORKDIR/
COPY     ./requirements.txt $WORKDIR/
ADD      . $WORKDIR
CMD      ["python", "/core/motion_detector.py --conf conf/conf.json"]
```

Building the image works fine, but when I tried to run it, I get the following error:

```
Joes-MacBook-Pro-78:project joe$ docker run joesan/dummy
python: can't open file '/raspi_motion_detection/project/core/motion_detector.py --conf /raspi_motion_detection/project/conf/conf.json': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
Joes-MacBook-Pro-78:project joe$
```

Any ideas as to what is happening? I did in fact ADD the WORKDIR to the Docker runtime, but still it would not find the necessary Python file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the last line of your Dockerfile:

```
CMD ["python", "/core/motion_detector.py --conf conf/conf.json"]
```

When the container starts up it is trying to launch `python` and pass it a single argument, which it interprets as the filename of a script to run.  That argument, *which is interpreted in its entirety as a script name*, is `/core/... conf/conf.json`.  Since you don't have a single file with that name, spaces and options and all, Python fails.

If you're using the JSON-ish syntax you need to break each separate argument into its own "word":

```
CMD ["python", "core/motion_detector.py", "--conf", "conf/conf.json"]
```

(Note that the `WORKDIR` directive globally changes the working directory for all subsequent commands, the default directory for `COPY` and `ADD` directives, and any `ENTRYPOINT` and/or `CMD` that eventually gets run.  There's no `$WORKDIR` variable you can reference, and I suspect variable expansion is actually causing files end up in the container root directory when you don't expect.  Try just `COPY ./ ./` to add content to the image.)

Answer (score 0):

Well you use fully qualified paths like they are relative.

Assuming that your Dockerfile is situated in the `raspi-motion-detection` folder in your project structure...

```
CMD      ["python", "/core/motion_detector.py", "--conf", "conf/conf.json"]
```

The `/core...` part (note I broke all the command parts into separate items) will actually point to a location relative to the root folder as it starts with a '/' and it should actially look from here:

```
/raspi_motion_detection/project/project/core/motion_detector.py
```

the same goes for the `conf/conf.json` that one will actually point to something relative to the WORKDIR. you might want to be more specific here too :-)

you can check your config by running something like:

```
docker run -it --rm your_image /bin/bash
```

and then look around how and what you actually added where with your build.

Your Dockerfile seems to be wrong on some points too

- You can not reference WORKDIR with $WORKDIR
- You copy a requirements.txt file but never run it so it will probably never do anything
- You see to copy the whole structure and dat will include the Dockerfile which is unnecessary

Hope it helps